# Use indicator function in regression equation

Tags: regression, conditional, indicator-function

I have 2 regression equations:

1st Regression:
$I_t = a_1 + \beta_1E_t+X'_t\delta_1+\epsilon_1$

2nd Regression:
$I_t = a_2 + \beta_2E_t+X'_t\delta_2+Y'_t\lambda_2+\epsilon_2$

The two regressions are the same, except for the additional term $Y'_t\lambda_2$ in the 2nd Regression.

I would like to summarize these two regressions in a single regression.
I have seen this in some economics papers, which I unfortunatelly cannot recall.

Maybe this is done with an indicator function?

In words, I want my regression equation to be read as:
"The regression equation basically looks like the 1st regression, but if the matrix $Y$ is included in the model as additional variables, the regression looks like the 2nd regression."
Or put differently, I am looking for the mathematical notation of an "if-statement" within the regression.

Could I use this notation:

$I_t = a_3 + \beta_3E_t+X'_t\delta_3+\mathbb{1}_{(t=k)}Y'_t\lambda_3+\epsilon_3$?

I hope this means "If $t=k$ the Matrix $Y$ is part of the model, but if $t \neq k$, then $Y$ is not part of the model.
Would this mathematical notation and its interpretation be correct?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your purpose? Why would you describe the model with a complicated, obscure notation rather than describing it directly?

Comment: You can always introduce an indicator *variable* $Z,$ so that $\lambda_2$ is the coefficient of its interaction with $Y^\prime_t.$

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I´d appreciate if you had a look at my edited post. Cheers.